# How do I read contents of browser from a Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application, ui-automation

I need to read the contents of a browser window from a console application in C#.

What is the best way to do it.

I'm trying to use Automation UI (by capturing process of the browser and creating a AutomationElement of that process) but since I'm very new to this concept. I don't know where to begin from.

Comment: What kind of browser would be used?

Comment: any kind. need read the content of the browser window through process

Comment: You can try using Selenium WebDriver: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: @Matthew - Selenium works great if you're writing code to automate the browser that's fully under the control of some test code (eg. open a specific page and use/test it); but AFAIK not so useful if you want to snoop on browser apps that are already running.

Comment: Prabesh, can you perhaps add more details to your scenario - what type of processing or parsing do you want to do if/when you detect that a certain page has been loaded?

Comment: A since-deleted answer mentioned HTMLAgility; that approach could work *if* you can extract the URL from the currently-running browser, and so long as the page doesn't rely on cookies or javascript - then you could load and parse a separate copy of the page yourself rather than accessing the existing DOM. But that depends on your specific scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you are trying to accomplish but please be also noting that AutomationElement works only with some browsers, not all, among which Opera is to be shot down first.